# Ошибка list expected at most 1 argument, got 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы

Встречал такое относительно `input`, но никогда относительно `list`
Ниже привожу элемент кода. В чём моя ошибка и как исправить?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import *
urls = ['https://www.sima-land.ru/kanctovary/shkolnye-tovary/opticheskie-pribory/', 'https://wmasteru.org/threads/Простой-парсер-товаров-с-amazon-с-помощью-beautifulsoup.22880/']
class PageDownload(urls):
    def ___init___(self):
        self.urls = urls

    def taking_things(self):
        for url in self.urls:
            s = requests.get(url)
            b = BeautifulSoup(s.text)
            self.title = b.select('soup.html.head.title')

        print(self.title)

p = PageDownload()
p.taking_things()
```

Далее текст ошибки

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kotov_or/PycharmProjects/PageDataDownloader/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    class PageDownload(urls):
TypeError: list expected at most 1 arguments, got 3
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Укажите в какой строке ошибка, и желательно полный текст ошибки.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Объявляя класс “class PageDownload(urls)” вы указали что хотите __унаследовать__ его от объекта “urls”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас в коде что-то странное творится, исправил:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class PageDownload:
    def __init__(self, urls):
        self.urls = urls

    def taking_things(self):
        for url in self.urls:
            s = requests.get(url)
            b = BeautifulSoup(s.content, 'html.parser')
            self.title = b.select_one('head > title')
            print(self.title)
    
urls = ['https://www.sima-land.ru/kanctovary/shkolnye-tovary/opticheskie-pribory/', 'https://wmasteru.org/threads/Простой-парсер-товаров-с-amazon-с-помощью-beautifulsoup.22880/']

p = PageDownload(urls)
p.taking_things()
```

---

Смотрите:

- `class PageDownload(urls):` - в скобках после названия класса указывается тип, от которого наследуется тот
- `def ___init___(self):` - тут опечатка 3 нижних подчеркивания, вместо двух

---

**PS.**

Я бы еще посоветовал заменить:

- `b = BeautifulSoup(s.text)` на `b = BeautifulSoup(s.content)`, и желательно с указанием парсера, например: `b = BeautifulSoup(s.content, "html.parser")` или `b = BeautifulSoup(s.content, "lxml")`
- А еще сам `select` выглядит странно -- элемента `soup` не должно быть на той странице, а вы ведь хотите заголовок страницы из тега `title` забрать, тогда так: `title = b.select('head > title')`

---

**PPS.**

По поводу ошибки, мне стало интересно почему так выходит и набросал небольшой пример:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('__init__:\nargs={}\nkwargs={}'.format(args, kwargs))

urls = Foo()
print()

class PageDownload(urls):
    def __init__(self, urls):
        self.urls = urls
```

Консоль:

```
__init__:
args=()
kwargs={}

__init__:
args=('PageDownload', (<__main__.Foo object at 0x000001D2FE773F60>,), {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'PageDownload', '___init___': <function PageDownload.___init___ at 0x000001D2FE7782F0>})
kwargs={}
```

Как видно из консоли, код, вызываемый при наследовании, передает в конструктор несколько параметров.

Получается, ошибка `TypeError: list expected at most 1 arguments, got 3` произошла, когда в конструктор `list` было передано больше параметров, чем тот рассчитан - т.е. ожидался 1 параметр, а получено 3.

Comment: Что касается, постскриптума, конкретно данный способ я взял из официальной документации BeautifulSoup. Но спасибо за совет. Так и сделаю.

Comment: @AgeofCreations, понятно :) Вы не совсем правильно поняли, то, что в `select` попадает -- это css-селектор, а на языке css-селектора `soup.html.head.title` -- это найти такой элемент: `<soup class="html head title"></soup>`, а в документации имелось другое -- это написание тега у самого объекта `BeautifulSoup`, т.е. в вашем случае это было бы:  `title = b.html.head.title`. Понимаете? Кст, если что, `select` возвращает список, но если вам нужен 1 элемент, вызывайте `select_one`

Comment: Спасибо, буду тестить и учту всё это :)

Comment: Ок. А как мета-теги получить? А то как ни пробую, возвращает либо пустое значение, либо None.

Comment: `meta_tags = b.select('head > meta')`, это найдет теги, что являются прямыми детьми `head`

Comment: То есть, для description это должно быть `b.select('head > meta > description')`?

Comment: Пожалуйста, пишите подробнее, я не телепат :) Вы про получение тега на примере `<meta property="og:description" content="В наличии 571 шт. по цене от 10.04 руб. Закажите прямо сейчас!">`?

Comment: Да, например. То есть, для какого-то конкретного мета-тега. Простите, плыву уже слегка под вечер :)

Comment: Попробуйте так: `b.select_one('meta[property="og:description"]')`, можно и так: `b.select_one('meta[property=og:description]')`

Comment: Всё, спасибо. Понял теперь как это работает.